# Problems with scripts

Tags: scripts

I am using Ubuntu (16.04 now) since some years, alongside a Win10 installation. That worked fine untill about a week ago, when the system went extremely slow under Ubuntu.  It halts working for a long time, dims the screen a couple of times and finally comes with a message that a script is running (often with the google name in the address shown)...
What could be the reason of this problem and how can I solve it?
Many thanks beforehand.

Comment: I think there may be a problem with your browser profile, are you using Firefox? Could you post the error? You may try resetting your browser profile.

Comment: Run `top` from your terminal to see what application / process is hogging CPU time and report that in your question.